# Output in a jsp fragment

Tags: jsp, struts2

so basically, I have a jsp page where I have a button to add rows in a table. When I click on this button, a Javascript script is executed. In this script, there is a part where I use this lines of code :

```
request.open("POST",action,true);
```

Where action :

```
var action = "changeRepresentative.action";
```

So from now on, the code is executed from a class called *ChangeRepresentativeAction*

```
public class ChangeRepresentativeAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware {}
```

In this class, I have an attribute called *response*

```
private HttpServletResponse response;
```

I also have an **execute** method

```
public String execute {
     ...
     response.setContentType("text/html");
     ...
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     ...
     out.print("<table width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"> <tr><td><table><tr>");
     //More out.print
     ...
}
```

My question is this one : instead of putting several lines of out.print in the Java code, is there a way to put all the html code in a jsp file ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways this could be done.

The easiest is to just use a JSP like normal, and in your JavaScript, take the response and shove it into the DOM:

```
$("#targetDiv").html(response);
```

I mean, that's precisely what you're doing now, but instead of using a JSP, you're doing it manually, in the action. I'm not sure why you're not just using a JSP for this in the first place.

Comment: I'm not the one who did it ^^

Comment: @DatNguyen Either way, just put it in a JSP; your calling code shouldn't even have to change, although hard to say since you don't show it.

Comment: I'll try that on Monday. As for the code, sorry since it's work related, I'd rather not show it. Thank you for your help